# Find which tmux session and pane runs a given process ID

Tags: tmux

Sometimes I'll find a process I started a long time ago from a shell but won't remember from which tmux session and pane I started it. How can I find out, given the process ID, from which session and pane I started it so that I can go to it and inspect what I was doing?